# Is there a chain of finitely generated modules $M_i$ not satisfying ascending chain condition s.t. $\cup_i M_i$ is finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

It is easy to find such a chain s.t. $\cup_i M_i$ is not finitely generated. So I am curious about the other situation. Can $\cup_i M_i$ be finitely generated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $M_i$ not satisfying acc? That each $M_i$ contains an ascending chain of submodules that does not stabilize?

Comment: If the union is finitely generated, then each of the finitely many elements in a finite generating set is in one of the $M_i$, and then taking $N$ to be the largest such index you get that the chain stabilizes.

Comment: @guidoar: He says “chain”, both in subject and body, so it’s hard to see how to read this to *not* mean “chain”.

Comment: That is indeed a good point :/ (and I should definitely read posts more carefully)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin My confusion came from the fact that he refers to the "other situation", I assumed that meant not a chain

Comment: @guidoar My reading was: “When the chain does not stabilize, it is easy to find a union that is not finitely generated. How about the other case, can there be a chain that does not stabilize but where the union is finitely generated?”

Comment: @guidoar: If you look at all four combinations (chain stabilizes, does not stabilize; union is finitely generated, is not finitely generated), then in fact the only combination that is impossible is that the chain does not stabilize but the union is finitely generated, for arbitrary modules. For finitely generated modules, then the chain stabilizes if and only if the union is finitely generated.

Comment: Yeah, it's clear to me now that you've said it; my bad.

Answer (score 0):

For the record: you are putting more information in the subject line than in the body. It should be the other way around! The body should be self-contained and include all relevant information, while the subject line gives a rough idea of what the question is about.

---

First, say $\{M_i\}_{i\in\omega}$  is an ascending chain of modules, and let $M=\cup_{i\in\omega}$ be their union, which is also a module. The chain "stabilizes" if and only if there exists $N\in\omega$ such that for all $m\geq N$, $M_m=M_N$.

First, let us put no conditions on any of the $M_i$. We have the following three examples:

1. The chain stabilizes and $M$ is finitely generated. Just take your favorite finitely generated module (say, a cyclic one), and let $M_i=M$ for all $i\in\omega$.
2. The chain stabilizes and $M$ is not finitely generated. Take your favorite non-finitely generated module (e.g., the free module on the set $\{x_i\}_{i\in\omega}$), and let $M_i=M$ for all $i\in\omega$.
3. The chain does not stabilize and $M$ is not finitely generated. Take your favorite non-finitely generated but countably generated module $M$ (e.g., the one mentioned above), let $X=\{m_i\}_{i\in\omega}$ be a generating set for $M$, and let $M_i=\langle x_0,\ldots,x_i\rangle$ for each $i\in\omega$. The chain never stabilizes, and the union is $M$, which is not finitely generated.

However,

**Proposition 1.** If $M$ is finitely generated, then the chain stabilizes.

*Proof.* Let $m_1,\ldots,m_k$ be a generating set for $M$. For each $j$, $1\leq j\leq k$, there exists $i_j\in\omega$ such that $m_j\in M_{i_j}$. Let $N=\max\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}$. Then $m_j\in M_{i_j}\leq M_N$ for all $j$, hence for all $n\geq N$,
$$M = \langle m_1,\ldots,m_k\rangle \leq M_N\leq M_n \leq M,$$
so we have equality throughout and in particular the chain stabilizes. $\Box$

If we also require each $M_i$ to be finitely generated, then example 2 no longer applies. In that case, we have:

**Proposition 2.** Let $\{M_i\}_{i\in\omega}$ be a chain of finitely generated modules. Then the chain stabilizes if and only if $M=\cup_{i\in\omega}M_i$ is finitely generated.

*Proof.* If the chain stabilizes, then there exists $N\in\omega$ such that $M=M_N$, and since $M_N$ is finitely generated, so is $M$. The converse is Proposition 1. $\Box$